# How to make variable in if statement point to chosen method when method shares the same name as another method?

Tags: java

The assignment in which I have been given is about scope. So I have no choice but to have two methods share the same name. I have done a calculation in both methods, one for multiplying and the other for adding. I have then written if statements that test if the validity of the statements are correct. This all seems to be working fine except both of my if statements are pointing to my multiplication method. I'm not sure how to make it so that my if statement which checks the validity of the adding method points to the method which does the adding calculation?

Here is the code:

```
**TestCalculator class**
public class TestCalculator {
        Double x;

 String string = "b";
 Double doubleObject = 1.0;
 double doublePrimitive = 2;


        /*
        * Chops up input on ' ' then decides whether to add or multiply.
        * If the string does not contain a valid format returns null.
        */

        public void testParsing() {

         if (x(12.0) == 17.0) {
            System.out.println("Adding Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Adding Fail");
                    }
         if (x(12.0) == 60) {
            System.out.println("Multiplying Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Multiplying Fail");
                    }
        }
        /*
        * Adds the parameter x to the instance variable x and returns the answer as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(Double x){
            System.out.println("== Adding ==");
            //Sum here
            this.x = x;
            return new Double(x + 5);
}
        /*
        * Multiplies the parameter x by instance variable x and return the value as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(double x){
                System.out.println("== Multiplying ==");
                this.x = x;
                return new Double(x * 5);
        }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestCalculator call = new TestCalculator();

call.testParsing();

}

}
```

I understand that the adding method is o a different data type to the other method. One is an object and the other primitive but I don't not how to make x in my adding if statement point to the method which adds two numbers instead of the method which multiplies the two numbers. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Here the best solution would be to rename the methods to `addX` and `multiplyX`.Or else you may have some perfect `autoboxing` problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that the adding method is o a different data type to the other method. One is an object and the other primitive

You are correct. `Double` is Java's wrapper class for the `double` primitive. You are calling your methods on `double` literals, which means that the method with the primitive parameter is being called. To use the method with the object `Double` parameter, you first have to convert your value to a `Double` using the `Double` constructor (i.e. `new Double(12.0)`). When you pass that to your method, Java will recognize it as the object and call the appropriate method.